# Quarkus + Panache + CRUD with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, crud, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to do a CRUD WebApp with Quarkus + Panache + CRUD with PostgreSQL.
I have some entity Pays, PaysDTO and resource PaysResource. everything works well except AddPays method:
In Pays entity:

```
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.Panache;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheEntityBase;
import io.quarkus.panache.common.Sort;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name = "pays")
public class Pays extends PanacheEntityBase {
...
    @Transactional
    public static Uni<Pays> addPays(Pays pays){
        return Panache
                .withTransaction(pays::persist)
                .replaceWith(pays) 
                .ifNoItem()       
                .after(Duration.ofMillis(10000)) 
                .fail() 
                .onFailure()  
                .transform(t-> new IllegalStateException(t));
    }
...
}
```

In PaysResource.java:

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import org.advplan.entity.Pays;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/api/pays")
public class PaysResource {
...
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Uni<Response> addOnePays(Pays pays){
        return Pays.addPays(pays)
                .onItem()
                .transform(id -> URI.create("/api/pays/" + id.id))
                .onItem()
                .transform(uri-> Response.created(uri))
                .onItem()
                .transform(Response.ResponseBuilder::build);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    public Uni<Response> updateOnePays(Long id, Pays pays){
        return pays.updatePays(id,pays)
                .onItem().transform(entity -> entity != null ? Status.OK : Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .onItem().transform(status -> Response.status(status).build());
    }
...
}
```

When try to add pays with:

```
curl -v  --location 'localhost:8080/api/pays' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": 221,
    "npays": "SENEGAL",
    "abbrevisation": "SEN",
    "createdat":"2021-12-08",
    "updatedat":"2021-12-08"
}'
```

OR

```
% curl -v -d '{"id": 221, "npays": "SENEGAL","abbreviation":"SEN","createdat":"2021-12-08","updatedat":"2021-12-08"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/api/pays/
```

I have this error:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api/pays HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 129
> 
* upload completely sent off: 129 out of 129 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: application/json
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"exceptionType":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","code":500,"error":"javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.advplan.entity.Pays"}* Closing connection 0
```

On Postman:

```
{
    "exceptionType": "java.lang.IllegalStateException",
    "code": 500,
    "error": "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.advplan.entity.Pays"
}
```

I'm trying to know how can I solve this error.
Inspire by this tutorial
https://medium.com/geekculture/creating-a-crud-shopping-service-with-quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-and-postgresql-using-active-41a755693f12

Answer (score 1):

I had a solution to my problem. This error occurs because i provided the data with an '**Id**' while it is generated by PanacheEntityBase automatically. Indeed the section:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "id", nullable = false)
public Long id;
```

leaves the management of the Id in panache. So when I provide the data without the 'id' like that:

```
curl -v  --location 'localhost:8080/api/pays' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "npays": "SENEGAL",
    "abbrevisation": "SEN",
    "createdat":"2021-12-08",
    "updatedat":"2021-12-08"
}'
```

All thing's well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I got a detach problem like you.

You can try marking the @Transactional annotation in the addOnePays method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).